# How to Integrate a Python model into an app that works on IOS and Android

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, cross-platform, integration

I am a beginner in developing mobile apps, I have a python model with me, and I am trying to build a mobile app using flutter or any other frameworks like react-native. Here the problem is I don't know How to integrate a python ML model into an app that works both on Android and IOS. There is a  path like converting a model into  TensorFlow lite  and import this file in android studios gradle and use it in-app

My primary concerns are

1. There are many files in my python ML model and I don't know how and what to convert into TensorFlow lite `.tflite`
2. The model mainly revolves around a pre-built standard model and a .py file that analyses the pre-built model, I don't know what to convert into (.tflite)
3. Is a single `.tflite` sufficient to handle the whole app (as many YouTubers have just used a single `.tflite` file in their app development).

Answer (score 0):

Pick the already trained model or retrain the model and save the model in .h5 format using this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#hdf5_format).

Convert .h5 file to .tflite using [Tflite converter](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/index).

Deploy to your device using [Tflite_interpreter](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference)